# How to echo and auto increment receipt number in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database, and table fees. In which I have to generate a receipt of each payment. But I want that receipt number field must first echo receipt number which is one increment (+1) of last receipt number. For example, last receipt is 1 than new receipt should be 2 and non editable.

I am bit confused in that.

My field code is:

```
<label class="field-title">Reciept Number <span class="form-req">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="reciept_number" class="span4" value="<?php 

$data =  max(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT reciept_number FROM fees"))); echo $data; ?>" readonly>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What happens when two people open the receipt form ?

Answer (score 1):

Dont understand your question exactly but maybe you want something like this:

```
<label class="field-title">Reciept Number <span class="form-req">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" name="reciept_number" class="span4" value="
<?php 
$data = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT max(reciept_number)+1 FROM fees")); 
echo $data[0]; 
?>" readonly>
```